# Applescript : click on button with JS

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I'm trying to use Applescript to automatically click on a button to download a file on Safari

I have tried several methods so far but nothing worked. Best case, it returns nothing at all and just go to the next part of the script.

The file to download changes for each request.

This is the class as it is shown on the webpage I work with:

```
<div id="events-table"> = $0
  <div class="bootstrap-table">
    <div class="fixed-table-toolbar">
      <div class="bs-bars pull-right">
        <div id="table-toolbar" class="ml-3">
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="/event_sequences/myfile.csv">Download CSV</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      <div class="columns column-right btn-group pull-right>...</div>
      ::after
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-table-container" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">...</div>
   </div>
   <div class="clear fix">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below are some codes I tried, none with any success

```
tell application "Safari"
do JavaScript "document.title = 'Download';" in current tab of window 1
end tell

tell application "Safari"
do JavaScript "document.title = 'Download CSV’;” in current tab of window 1
end tell

tell application "Safari" to ¬
do JavaScript ¬
"document.querySelectorAll(\"[href=\\\"Download CSV\\\"]\")[0].click();" in current tab of window 1
```

I have also tried doing it "manually" but it didn't work either as it looks like I can't figure out how to reach the button:

```
Tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    set frontmost to true

    repeat 7 times
        keystroke option
        keystroke (ASCII character 9)

    end repeat
    keystroke return
end tell
```

When I try to reach the button manually on the page, 7 Option Tab are exactly what I need to reach it but if I use the script, it goes below and replaces some values in fields below the button. I tried increasing and decreasing the repeats with no success.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Also, when I use the inspector on the button, it returns: a.btn.btn-default 122px x 34px Role link

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are truing to download the file from?

Comment: it's an internal page, it cannot be accessed outside the company

Comment: It works! wonderful, thank you so much! I tried something extremely similar and I don't understand why it didn't work! Really, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the only download button on the page with that `class` name, then try the following:

```
tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default')[0].click();" in document 1
```